# Install python 3.5 inside docker with a base image centos7

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I  am trying to install python 3.5 inside docker with a base image centos7. This is our Dockerfile

```
FROM base-centos7:0.0.8
# Install basic tools
RUN yum install -y which vim wget git gcc
# Install python 3.5
RUN yum install -y https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm \
    && yum update -y \
    && yum install -y python35u python35u-libs python35u-devel python35u-pip


RUN python3.5 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

But during the build,  docker build image is failing with the following errors

```
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum install -y https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm
&& yum update -y
&& sudo yum install -y python35u python35u-libs python35u-devel python35u-pip]: exit code: 127.
```

Can anyone guide me in resolving this issue. and why am I seeing this issue in very first place.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve]; a later comment suggests the `base-centos7` image is a custom image so it's hard to tell what's going on.  The complete error from the `yum install` step would also be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use python image from docker hub

https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Example of dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "/code/app.py"]
```

i think it's easy , isn't ?

Comment: I need to use the centos image as it already have some projects dependencies installed. So i need to install py3.5 in the same centos image.

Comment: Please , follow this : https://gist.github.com/pvergain/6c45d0859c10ca2341512c69d46167b2

Comment: Btw, why i am seeing the issue in the very first place?

Answer (score -1):

the centos repo uses:

```
FROM centos/s2i-base-centos7

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.5 \
    PATH=$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off




RUN INSTALL_PKGS="rh-python35 rh-python35-python-devel rh-python35-python-setuptools rh-python35-python-pip nss_wrapper \
        httpd24 httpd24-httpd-devel httpd24-mod_ssl httpd24-mod_auth_kerb httpd24-mod_ldap \
        httpd24-mod_session atlas-devel gcc-gfortran libffi-devel libtool-ltdl enchant" && \
    yum install -y centos-release-scl && \
    yum -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install --enablerepo=centosplus $INSTALL_PKGS && \
    rpm -V $INSTALL_PKGS && \
    # Remove centos-logos (httpd dependency) to keep image size smaller.
    rpm -e --nodeps centos-logos && \
    yum -y clean all --enablerepo='*'
```

source [here](https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/blob/master/3.5/Dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks @Lucas. Also i am trying to run another command but failing with `/bin/sh: python3.5: command not found`

 `RUN python3.5 -m pip install /usr/local/share/apps/engine
`

Comment: @ben if Python 3.5 is the only version installed, then don't use the versioned binary, just run `python -m pip`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not difficult, I build the image changing

`FROM base-centos7:0.0.8` ====> `FROM centos:7`

You can consult the images version of centos in https://hub.docker.com/_/centos

PD: The container showed: errro exited(1), you should focus on the main process.

Comment: I am not using the image from https://hub.docker.com/_/centos, so you will not find this image reference 'base-centos7:0.0.8'. This image is present in my local.

Comment: Then can you write the Dockerfile of the base-centos7:0.0.8 image?

Comment: You should/must include everycode you have made. Then I could help you.